# How to select records 30 days apart from each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, lag, gaps-and-islands

I have a subset of records that look like this:

```
ID DATE
A  2015-09-01
A  2015-10-03
A  2015-10-10
B  2015-09-01
B  2015-09-10
B  2015-10-03
...
```

For each ID I want to select all records that are 30 days apart from each other while ignoring the dates in between.

For example, for ID A, 2015-09-01 and 2015-10-03 would be selected since they are more than 30 days apart.  2015-10-10 would be dropped because it's within 30 days of the 2nd date.

For ID B, 2015-09-10 would be dropped because it's within 30 days of the 1st index record.  2015-10-03 would be selected because it's greater than 30 days of the 1st date.

The output should look like this:

```
ID DATE
A  2015-09-01
A  2015-10-03
B  2015-09-01
B  2015-10-03
```

I have used LAG/LEAD functions which seem to only work for immediate prev/next records (i.e. ID A).  My problem is when I have to ignore dates within the 30 day time frame (i.e. ID B - how do I ignore 2015-09-10 while keeping 2015-10-03)?

Comment: Will there always only be 3 dates in each ID group?

Comment: Since you don't know which rows are the start of each group, until you have checked all previous rows, this can be quite complex to do with set based approach. Maybe a cursor would even be the simplest way to solve this.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions

Comment: i posted an answer on your previous question. see if it works with your data.

Comment: Sorry I am new here, i didn't know we are not allowed to repost a question.  I was trying to reword the question since it seemed like people didn't understand the problem.  I will look at the other answers, thanks.  Not sure how to write a cursor for the problem any help would be greatly appreciated.